# How to grow a tree (svg) to a line (flex)?

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

Example of what I need:

[image]

My code in [JSBIN](http://output.jsbin.com/wafuce)

I've tried without success.

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply insert a div in the corresponding place in the DOM on the right-hand-side (i.e as the div's first child), giving it a width and height of `4rem` like the image has? I.e - `<div id="rightSpacer" style="width:4rem; height: 4rem;"></div>` Also - that's a huge png that's embedded inside that SVG - the PNG is some 200kb or more, yet the tree is only displayed at 68x68pixels. (4,624 pixels)You can re-trace the bitmap as SVG paths and get a very similar looking image for just 15kb. Far smaller if you use a png.